# Cufon text z-index (IE6 and IE7 stylish select box bug)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, cufon

I'm replacing some text with cufon on my page and I'm using jquery stylish select box plugin (http://www.scottdarby.com/plugins/stylish-select/0.4/) to style select boxes.

The problem is that, in IE6 and IE7, select box goes under the cufonized text. (the select box is actually an `<ul>`).

Anyone had this issue before?

Comment: oh, sorry, *the select box is actually an unordered list. got stripped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i encountered the same problem with a drop down menu, through which the Cufon h1 stays visible in IE 6 & 7. Giving the element in which the ul is placed a z-index solves the problem!
Cheers

Comment: Ya, it creates a new stacking order for indexing I think.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem, but becouse cufon was relative posioned. Z-index + positon relative for menu item solved my problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the fact that cufon uses absolute positioning on elements which overlaps your select list, AJs answer should work but if you like more background on it ask your  [searchengine](http://www.google.co.nz/search?q=ie6+z-index+absolute&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)